# $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \cos^2(2^k) \to ?$ as $n \to \infty$

Tags: limits

WolframAlpha claims that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \cos^2(2^k) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+%28sum%28%5Ccos%282%5Ek%29%5E2%2Ck%3D1%2Cn%29%29%2Fn+as+n-%3Einfinity

I doubt: By $\cos^2(2^{k+1})=(2\cos^2(2^k)-1)^2$ and Jensen's inequality applied to the convex function $x \mapsto  x^2$ (or Cauchy Schwarz)
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \cos^2(2^k)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n (2\cos^2(2^{k-1})-1)^2
\ge \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n (2\cos^2(2^{k-1})-1)\right)^2
$$
$$
= \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n (2\cos^2(2^{k-1}))-1\right)^2 = \left(\frac{2}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (\cos^2(2^{k}))-1\right)^2.
$$
Now let $(n_j)$ be a sequence with
$$
\frac{1}{n_j}\sum_{k=1}^{n_j} \cos^2(2^k) \to s:= \liminf_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \cos^2(2^k) \quad (j \to \infty).
$$
Then
$$
\frac{1}{n_j}\sum_{k=0}^{n_j-1} \cos^2(2^k) \to s \quad (j \to \infty),
$$
and therefore $s \ge (2s-1)^2$, that is $4s^2-5s+1 \le 0$. Thus $s \in [1/4,1]$.

Two questions:

1. Is this correct?
2. Numerical experiments indicate $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \cos^2(2^k) \to \frac{1}{2}$ as $n \to \infty$. Does anybody know a proof?

Thanks for any helpful comment.

Edit: I replaced $\limsup$ by $\liminf$ (same proof but more information).

Comment: Heuristics: \begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\cos ^2 (2^k )}  & = \frac{1}{n}\int_2^n {\cos ^2 (2^x )dx}  + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right) = \frac{1}{{\log 2}}\frac{1}{n}\int_1^{2^n } {\frac{{\cos ^2 (t)}}{t}dt}  +  \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right)\\ & = \frac{1}{{\log 2}}\frac{1}{n}\left( {\frac{1}{2}\log (2^n)  +  \mathcal{O}(1)} \right) +  \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right) = \frac{1}{2} +  \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right)
\end{align*}

Comment: @Gary Looks interesting. However, I don't see the first equality. For this $\sum_{k=1}^n\cos^2(2^k)- \int_2^n \cos^2(2^x)dx$ should be bounded. How can this be seen?

Comment: That is why I wrote "heuristics". The argument is correct iff $$
\int_2^n {\cos ^2 (2^x )d\left\{ x \right\}}  = \mathcal{O}(1)
$$ as $n\to +\infty$

Comment: I see. Thank's. I will think about it.

Comment: The sum is also $$
\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{{2n}}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\cos (2^{k + 1} )} 
$$ so it is enough to show that the cosine sum is $o(n)$.

Comment: What is the limit for degrees? The sum is periodic.

Comment: It is known that $2^k a \!\!\mod\! 1$ is uniformly distributed for almost all, but not all, irrational $a$. So if it was true for $a=1/\pi$ then we would have $$
\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\cos (2^{k + 1} )}  = \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\cos \left( {2\pi \left\{ {\frac{{2^k }}{\pi }} \right\}} \right)}  \to \int_0^1 {\cos (2\pi x)dx}  = 0.
$$

Comment: @Empy2 ... For **degrees**, $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\cos(2^k\pi/180)^2$ : the answer is $1/2$.  Start with two terms $\cos(\pi/90)^2+\cos(\pi/45)^2$, then repeat a period of $12$ terms with average value $1/2$.  So limit is $1/2$.